# net.masterthought maven-cucumber-reporting: the link for the embedding image file is not displayed in the overview feature html

Tags: maven, automation, cucumber, report

I have cucumber selenium automatin java project with:
I am using cucumber 4.8.1, and maven-cucumber-reporting 4.3.0

I am using mvn clean install in my local machine to execute the test
When I have an error, the cucumber.json file includes the screenshot:

```
   "after": [
      {
        "embeddings": [
          {
            "data": "iVBORw0KGgoAA..."
            "mime_type": "image/png"
          }
        ],
```

And in the output folder the embeddings folder is created and includes the screenshot correctly

This is my plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                        <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation
                            of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                        <skip>false</skip> 
                        <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                        <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                        <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</inputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                            <param>**/cucumber.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                        <classificationDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</classificationDirectory>
                        <classificationFiles>
                            <param>sample.properties</param>
                            <param>other.properties</param>
                        </classificationFiles> 
                        <!-- optional, set true to fail build on test failures -->
                        <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But, in the overview-features.html file when I open the error in the step, after the error the link to display the screenshot is not displayed.

Do you know what is missing or wrong?

Many thanks
Xavier

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED !!!!**

**Now the link to the screenshot is inside the Hooks Section**

In the previous versions (I was working with cucumber 1.2.5 and maven-cucumber-reporting 4.3.0), the link "Attachment.1 (png) was placed directly in the steps section, not in the Hooks.

In the new version of the maven-cucumber-reporting the link with the print screen captured is inside the Hooks section, then, you need first to open the Hooks section in the bottom of the scenario results, and the link to the Attachement.1 (png) is displayed.

After several days I have found the solution. The ticket can be closed!!!

I hope this can help other people with the same problem!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have tried to clarify the answer, regards!